# Integration of XC16 into Visual Studio Makefile Project

Tags: c, visual-studio, makefile, pic, xc16

Has anyone successfully created a Makefile Project within Visual Studio that utilizes the Makefiles generated by MPLAB X and will build code targeted at a PIC24? Or do I need to create my own Makefile that targets xc16-gcc? It would be beneficial to use the same format as MBLAB X should Microchip’s IDE be required at some point.

I’m looking to create a platform independent application, in C, with the goal of write (and test) it once, use it everywhere; should commonality exists. Through the use of build switches and the appropriate Makefile the non-common aspects can then enabled and targeted at the specific platform. It seems like Visual Studio will allow me to take this approach from what I have read, but I can’t find anything specific to PICs, just AVR/Arduino which I haven’t been able to get to work.

Thanks.

HL

Comment: You are looking for a multi-platform makefile.  The makefile will not be platform independent.  It will be dependent on the platform.  You'll have to lookup tools like cmake and imake.  It will be a two stage process.  I can't give you any examples as the last time I did this was over 20 years ago.

Comment: That was my suspicion, but thought it worth asking if there was a more straight forward way before jumping in at the deep end.

Comment: You could have a look at scons but it needs python.  https://scons.org/

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if this is the best approach. I'm currently exporing the possibility of using project extensibility in Visual Studio by which to integrate xc16-gcc into VS